# How do I disconnect a user from a voice channel

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm trying to make it so when someone joins a voice chat it will disconnect a user

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
  guild = client.get_guild(id)
  member = guild.get_member(id)
  if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
   await member.disconnect()
```

but when I run the code, it gives me a error:

```
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'disconnect'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disconnect members from voice channels using `await member.move_to(None)` instead of `await member.disconnect()`

---

References:

- [member.move_to](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.move_to)

Answer (score 0):

You kick a member from the voice channel they're in with voiceState.kick(). You can get a member's voiceState with member.voice.

[Source Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/fpthx8/disconnecting_an_user_from_voice_chat_when_a/flmzhlg?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: That's for discord.js